# How do I separate a variable from the rest of my Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex where the variable `$m_strFirstName` is next to other identifier characters that aren't part of the variable name:

```
if($strWholeName =~ m/$m_strFirstName_(+)/) 
....
```

I'm trying to extract something like:

- strWholeName is 'bob_jones' or 'bob_smith'
- m_strFirstName is 'bob'
- and I want the 'smith' or 'jones' part of the string.
- if strWholeName is "frank_jones" I want to ignore that, so the if statement would be false

Obviously,

```
m/$m_strFirstName_(+)/
```

is not going to work because the regex interpreter won't treat the $m_strname part as I intended, so any ideas?

**EDIT: my original question was not clear, updated.**

Thanks

Comment: Won't something like split() do the trick ==> my (undef, $lname) =split(/_/, $strname);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put braces around your variable name:

```
if($strname =~ m/${m_strName}_(.+)/)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be m/${m_strName}_(.+)/ (missing the dot)

Comment: Using m/\Q${m_strName}\E_(.+)/ should be safer.

Comment: Because you haven't anchored the regex, this will incorrectly match e.g. a $strname of "jeanne_smith" to a $m_strName of "anne".

Answer (score 3):

Josh has the right answer, but if you turned on strict and warnings, you could have found it for yourself.  Here's (basically) your script as it was originally:

```
my($strWholeName) = "Bob_Jones";
my($m_strFirstName) = "Bob";

if($strWholeName =~ m/$m_strFirstName_(.+)/) {
    print "Last name is <$1>\n";
}
```

which resulted in the following:

```
C:\temp>perl test.pl
Last name is <Bob_Jones>
```

If you add the following two lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

you get the following output instead:

```
C:\temp>perl test.pl
Global symbol "$m_strFirstName_" requires explicit package name at test.pl line
7.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Add in the braces per Josh's answer and you finally get:

```
C:\temp>perl test.pl
Last name is <Jones>
```

Always, always, always `use strict` and `use warnings`!

See [brian's Guide to Solving Any Perl Problem](http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/A2.brians_guide.html) from *Mastering Perl* for more nifty tricks.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($strWholeName =~ m/^\Q$m_strFirstName\E_(.+)/)
```

Differences from Josh Kelley's answer:

1. You must **anchor** the regex to the start of the string, otherwise e.g. a `$strWholeName` of "jeanne_smith" will incorrectly match a `$m_strFirstName` of "anne".
2. You should surround `$m_strFirstName` with `\Q` and `\E` to **quote any strange characters** (unless you are absolutely sure they cannot appear -- but why not do it anyway as it is cheap and guarantees safety).  Hynek Vychodil mentioned this in a comment on Josh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$foo = "yodeling yoda"
$bar = "ing yo"

if ($foo =~ /\Q$bar\E/)
{
  print "true"
}
```

Comment: I tend to use the \Q...\E because something about breaking up my dollar signs and the identifiers with which they belong rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: +1 \Q\E is a good habit to get into for interpolating into regexen at all times.  Only omit them if you know that you really want to.